# count total number of list items in unordered list using php

Tags: php, html

I want to count the total number of items within an ordered list, i though this would be a fairly common question on Google but apparently not.

I have tried using PHP's count function but im not sure if it works for lists as it appears to be only relevant to PHP arrays.

```
echo '<p>' . count($TheList, 1) . '</p>';
```

The total of the list should appear in a paragraph within a Div lower down my page but it throws an error.

The list looks like this:

```
echo '<ul id="TheList" >';
echo '<li> peas </li>';
echo '<li> carrots </li>';
echo '<li> onions </li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

Really all i am trying to do is count how many items are in the unordered list.

Comment: Why don't you use javascript for this?

Comment: Show the full code. or at least the value of $TheList variable.

Comment: @RahilWazir I was originally planning on using JQuery to do that but im not sure how to pass the PHP variable to the external script, im new to PHP so im very uncertain as to what to use

Comment: @hindmost the  $TheList variable is an unordered list shown directly below what ive tried already

Comment: @KyleT this is what you need in jQuery `$('#TheList > li').length;`

Comment: @RahilWazir great answer, this was the solution i needed. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to count DOM elements, you should use an HTML parser. Here's an example with **[DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)**

```
$html = '<ul id="TheList">
<li> peas </li>
<li> carrots </li>
<li> onions </li>
</ul>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($html);

print $doc->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
```

OUTPUT:

> 3

This works even if the list items have attributes (ids, classes, etc...) or strange formats. Example:

```
$html = '<ul id="TheList">
<li      > peas </li>
<li id="foo"> carrots </li>
<li class="bar"> onions </li>
</ul>';
```

Comment: Hi Tivie, i managed to find a solution using JQuery as provided by another member. This is also a great example thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there are more appropriate ways to do this, but in the intrests of learning, here is a way you could use php to count the number of list items in a string of html code...

```
$liststring = "<ul id=\"TheList\" >"
    . "<li> peas </li>"
    . "<li> carrots </li>"
    . "<li> onions </li>"
    . "</ul>";


$numitems = substr_count($liststring, "<li>");

echo "<p>$numitems</p>";

echo $liststring;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to process html code, you could try to do this:

```
function count_list($list){
   $array = explode("</li>",$list);
   return count($list)-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is Server Side while HTML is presentation at Client Side.

If you generate those `li` elements from a PHP script, than you can just save the count when echoing the results and echo the `Count` of it everywhere you want.

I'm guessing you're not using some PHP script in order to generate and echo the list, therefore you can use `JavaScript` to help you solve this case.

**JavaScript code:**

```
<html>

    <head>
            <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="TheList_Count">0</p>
        <ul id="TheList">
            <li> peas </li>
            <li> carrots </li>
            <li> onions </li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("TheList_Count").innerHTML = document.getElementById("TheList").children.length;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi i was originally trying to use JQuery to do this but wasnt sure how to pass the PHP variable to the script. thanks for your answer

Comment: @KyleT, You welcome, You didn't tagged `jQuery` and didn't mentioned it so i didn't displayed `jQuery` example altough it make the code be very short. Also be advised that when echoing results using php from a variable you can always count that variable using normal plain PHP command to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using javaScript?

```
var theList = document.getElementById("TheList").getElementsByTagName("li");
var numberOfItems = theList.length;
```

Comment: Thanks Hydrogirl, i was originally using JQuery to try to solve the issue but wasnt sure how to pass the variable from PHP to the script as i am new to PHP.